# Unity c#: setting a GameObject to active from a script in a prefab

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject

I am running a script from within a prefab that is instantiated in the scene. The script is run when the pregab is cliked on. I want to be able to set QuestionScreen to true to make it visible and to close the game so that only the questionscreen is shown.

I have tried adding the game objects to the UFO script attached to the prefab, and I have tried using tags to select them.
The code works for the game GameObject but not for the question screen.
The tags are set correctly.
I have tried running the function from another script but it still is only run when the prefab is clicked on.

```
public void ScreenSwitch()
{
    GameObject Game = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("GameScreen");
    GameObject QuestionScreen = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Question");
    Debug.Log(QuestionScreen);
    Debug.Log(Game);
    Game.SetActive(false);
    QuestionScreen.SetActive(true);
}

public void OnMouseDown()
{
    ScreenSwitch();
    Debug.Log("Spaceship clicked");
```

Comment: `FindGameObjectWithTag` doesn't exist. You're either using `FindWithTag` which [specifically only searches for active objects](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindWithTag.html) or [`FindGameObject/s/WithTag`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag.html) which returns an array. And also only active objects.

Comment: @Draco18s It exists (at least in some versions) but it's undocumented. It's equivalent to `FindWithTag`.

Comment: @Ruzihm That's...mildly annoying.